# How to start and stop subprocess from flask

Tags: python, flask, subprocess

I have a flask app, from which I need to start few other apps (webrtc chats.)
I can easily do it with gunicorn, but my problem is how to start 5-10-15 or more webrtc apps( can do this with gunicorn command) and then stop some of them but not all.

So with this:

```
gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 --certfile /path/to/file --keyfile /path/to/file -b 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:app
```

command to start the server, each manager will start a server on its own port, no problems here. But how to store a process and then kill it, when the manager no longer needs server? I have no idea--any tips?

```
args = 'exec ' + gunicorn_command_above
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

So i can start servers with commands above, but don't know how to store and then kill process,
thx for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

If someone need, seems idea from [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)  works

```
p = subprocess.Popen("exec " + cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
# and after, we can kill this group with
os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
```